# How to prevent file hotlinking without a format?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I know hot to prevent hotlinking my images editing my .htaccess file. But I also have another server to host other files, but the download link has no extension. It is something like: `http://example.com/index.php/RANDOMKEY/download`.

How would I apply that filter in my server? I tried this but no success:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http(s)?://(www\.)?example.com [NC]
RewriteRule \(download)$ https://example.com/dontcopy.png [NC,R,L]
```

Comment: Remove the backslash from you RewriteRule.

Comment: Omg, how did I miss it. Hours trying for it to work. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

For all users of Nextcloud, that wants to stops someone from hotlinking your public shared links, use this, as mentioned by @starkeen.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http(s)?://(www\.)?example.com [NC]
RewriteRule (download)$ https://example.com/dontcopy.png [NC,R,L]
```

Where https://example.com/dontcopy.png is the adress of the image you want to display when someone steals your link.